# Java RSAPublicKey factory exception

Tags: java, exception, rsa, public-key

After upgrading Java to 1.8.0_171 I am always getting the following exception during RSA public key composing:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: exponent is larger than modulus
```

It was working before upgrade, does anyone know what to do with it?

```
RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus), new BigInteger(exponent));
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pub = factory.generatePublic(publicSpec); <----- EXCEPTION
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the upgrade is the cause, it may just be a coincidental timing. That error message is a pretty good indication that your data sources for the modulus and/or the exponent have been corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out that there was a change in Java from [1.8.0_161](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html) referenced by JDK-8174756:

> security-libs/javax.crypto
>   RSA public key validation
>
> In 8u161, the RSA implementation in the SunRsaSign provider will reject any RSA
>   public key that has an exponent that is not in the valid range as defined by
>   PKCS#1 version 2.2. This change will affect JSSE connections as well as
>   applications built on JCE.
>
> JDK-8174756 (not public)

Which basically means that modulus shouldn't be negative.
In that case, it is important to build `BigInteger` in the following manner to be positive:

```
BigInteger(1, modulus)
BigInteger(1, exponent)
```

After that change, it works again.